# Experience Optimization with web 8.5 not able find Processors tag

Tags: experience-optimization, deployer-conf

I am following the below document

[Adding Experience Optimization to Content Deployer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2#docid=GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web+Experience+Optimization-v2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3D%255C%2522deployer%255C-conf%255C%2522&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1489933196309&currentQuery=%255C%2522deployer%255C-conf%255C%2522&currentScope=)

but, I am not able to find the processors tag, as we have new deployer-conf, can I create this tag and place anywhere in deployer-conf or is there any other place to do so??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the **wrong documentation**. Experience Optimization is part of Web 8.5 now and as such has been merged into the same documentation publication. You'll notice that there isn't a separate link for it anymore when 8.5 is selected in the drop-down list.

The correct documentation page is therefore here: 
[Adding Experience Optimization to Content Deployer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-E87C6C4B-C7F7-432D-8649-9EE6BCC613C8)

And it does indeed involve changing the *deployer-conf* file as well as *tcdl-conf*.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, according to this page: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-C63D7500-32C6-4FB6-A6D0-B25599CB6A30 Processors and Processsor has been replaced by Pipelines and Pipeline. Pipelines contain Steps and Steps contain Modules.

I do not see any specific documentation on how to migrate but it looks like if you can figure out the Pipelines>Pipeline>Step>Module config structure ( Web 8.5 and up) in comparison to the Processors>Processor>Module config structure (pre Web 8.5) it should work.

Comment: Thank you.. let me try out. ., there are lots of conflicts in the document for experience optimization configuration.. not just this :-(

Comment: That's because you aren't looking at the 8.5 documentation :)