# Error while opening business process type web 8.5

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, experience-optimization

After installing SDL Web Experience Optimization 8 on Web 8.5, when I open business process type I am getting below error..

*Method not found: 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService Tridion.Web.CMUtils.CMSession.get_CoreServiceClient()'. Do you want to close this window?*

Error Details:

*at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.CoreService.CoreServiceFacade.GetInstance()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.DataExtenders.STDataExtender.ProcessGetBusinessProcessTypeResponse(XmlReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.DataExtenders.STDataExtender.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(DataExtender extender)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderParameterInspector.AfterCall(String operationName, Object[] outputs, Object& returnValue, Object correlationState)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)*

Am I missing something..!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you installed the previous version of Experience Optimization on top of 8.5 (especially considering [this other question you asked](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16742/experience-optimization-with-web-8-5-not-able-find-processors-tag)). However, XO is just a feature in the suite installer now. You don't install it separately.

You'll need to uninstall the old one and modify your SDL Web 8.5 installation to include Experience Optimization.

Comment: You are simply awesome..!! Thank you peter, you have saved a lot of time.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: fredhopper and smarttarget is always a problem, there should some single click installation..!!

Comment: Let me know if you want to help! https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Web-8.5-Quick-Install/issues/4  - I didn't find the time yet to look at it...